# Entering 20 numbers into an array with no duplicates

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int theArray [20] = {0};
    int userInput = 0;
    int populateCount = 0;
    cout << "Enter 20 integers between 10 and 100 inclusive. " << endl;
    while (populateCount < 20)
    {
        cin >> userInput;
        theArray[populateCount] = {userInput};
        if (userInput<10||userInput>100)
        {
            cout << "That is not a legal input. " << endl;
            populateCount - 2;
        }
        else
        {
            populateCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << theArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I've got the baseline of my code done. The user enters twenty numbers and they're added to the array. If it's less than 10 or greater than 100 it's not a legal input, I subtract from the count, and they're allowed to go again. Then after the user finishes plugging in numbers it prints the array. However, I've been trying different if statements inside the array to eliminate duplicates, such as (if theArray[i] == theArray[i+1] then [i+1] = 0) I suppose that could work if I incorporated a sort to get all the 0's at the end, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Just sort the array, then use two pointers to do the de-duplicates. Or you can store them in vector and use STL algorithms

Comment: Well, a naive solution would be to iterate the array, and see if the number exists before adding it. You could also use a [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), if you are allowed to use the standard library. Iterating would be insanely fast on 20 numbers, but if that was say, 10000 numbers, you'd probably want to use a set.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

Comment: As @crush said, use (STL set) [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/]. Or if your objective is to explore the algorithm itself: you know that your input is limited to 100. Get a 100 sized array and initialize all with a flag. Every number you add, add them in the index directly. After insertion, prints only positions different from the flag.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita even easier, just make the array an array of bools, and set them to true when you 'insert' them. Then you don't have to worry about flag value colliding with input values.

Comment: You don't need a vector to use STL algorithms.  They work fine on nearly any kind of array or sequence container.  The only limitations for each algorithm are documented.  Some require random access, and not all iterators types provide that. lower_bound and binary_search could be helpful depending on whether you keep it sorted during insertions or sort after all insertions.

Answer (score 1):

Before I go to the answer I suggest we clean it up slightly to make the problem more clear and remove other confusion.

### Misconception

The statement `populateCount - 2` has no effect.. instead you are simply not incrementing `populateCount` which is why the loop doesn't advance.

I would suggest something of this format within the loop. It puts the 'happy' path first, which will also make for some clearer ways to handle the second part.

```
if (userInput >= 10 && userInput <= 100 ) {
    theArray[populateCount++] = userInput;
} 
else {
    std::cout << userInput << " is not legal input, must enter value "
              << "between 10 and 100. " << std::endl;
}
```

### Preface

Before we attack the problem first let's refactor so that we can break it down to a single function so that as we work we don't disturb everything else as well as gain flexibility for testing and simplify readability.

### Refactor

```
/* this code is responsible for doing what is needed to 
 * only insert unique items */
bool insert( const int& input, int* array, int num_elements ) {
    // the fun part!
    // more to follow shortly
};

/* gets user input forcing input to be between min and max */
int getUserInput(int min, int max) {
    bool found = false;
    int result = 0; 
    /* this can be done with less code but this makes it easy
     * to see whats going on */
    while ( !found ) {
        cout << "Please enter a value between " << min << " and " << max << "." << endl;
        cin >> result;
        if ( result >= min && result <= max ) {
            found = true; //yes we could break or return from here
        } else {
            cout << result << " invalid. "<< endl;
        }
    }
    return result;
};

void printArray( const int* array, const int& size ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int totalElements = 20;
    int theArray [totalElements] = {0};
    int userInput = 0;
    int populateCount = 0;
    int minVal = 10;
    int maxVal = 100;
    cout << "Enter " << totalElements << " integers between " 
         << minVal << " and " << maxVal << " inclusive. " << endl;
    while ( populateCount < numElements )
    {
        //this will percievably loop until it's good
        userInput = getUserInput(minVal, maxVal);
        if ( insert( userInput, theArray, populateCount ) )
            ++populateCount; //increments if we did insert it
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    printArray( theArray, totalElements );
}
```

## Attacking the problem

Ok so now our problem is simple, we just have to write the `insert` function.  There are a couple of choices here, you can check each element in turn which as you said can be slow, O(n), or we could sort the array to make it quick, O(log n) + cost of sorting.  Other possibilities I presume aren't available are using a std::set instead of an array, or using STL to do the work of sorting and finding. **Note that in these modes `insert` won't actually do an insertion if the number is already present.**

Another unique idea is to use an array of bools size max-min, and simply flag the index of input-min as true when you find it.  This will be fast at the cost of size depending upon the gap between min and max. (this is essentially a hash function)

The advantage we are at from a refactor is that you can in turn write and try each of these solutions and even feed them the same canned input now that we've refactored so that you can try and time each one.  For timing I would heavily suggest you add lots of numbers and consider greatly expanding the min and max to understand the scalability of each choice

Comment: Using lower_bound would be a useful enhancement to this approach.  That will tell you whether you need to insert at all so no duplicates will ever be inserted in the first place.

Comment: @shawn1874 I'm not sure what you are getting at here but it seems as though you didn't read my answer. In all cases I've covered I'm not inserting duplicates into the array, and I also explicitly assumed that we can't use STL do the work.